# Erro : subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c

Ola, boa tarde, estou tentando pegar os valores que estão na minha matriz na função, mas esta dando esse problema:1:19: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Segue abaixo o código da função:

```
int contagemlinha(int* matriz, int N)
{
    int i, j, soma;

    for(i = 0, j = 0; j < N; j++)
    soma += matriz[i][j];

    return soma;
}
```

é errado tenta alocar em um inteiro de int esses valores??grato

Comment: Não é necessário incrementar `i` também? `i++;` abaixo de `soma += ..`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O tipo de `matriz` é um pointeiro (array) de inteiros. Nesse caso, quando você tem a operação `matriz[i]`, o valor que você tem é um inteiro. O problema é que você está tentando acessar o índice `[j]` desse valor inteiro.

Você precisa declarar o parâmetro `matriz` como um *array de arrays* (ou ponteiro de ponteiros) para poder acessá-la via dois índices, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
int contagemlinha(int ** matriz, int L, int C) {
    int i, j, soma = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < C; j++)
            soma += matrix[i][j];
    return soma;
}
```

Uma outra forma de se armazenar matrizes bidimensionais é armazená-la em um array simples, com os elementos da primeira linha seguidos dos elementos da segunda, e assim por diante. Por exemplo, a matriz

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

Pode ser armazenada no array

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Se é esse o seu caso, então você só precisa percorrer a matriz com um índice:

```
int contagemlinha(int* matriz, int N)
{
    int i, soma = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        soma += matriz[i];

    return soma;
}
```